# Split csv file into specified number of files without page break

Tags: powershell, split, filesplitting

I have a 200,000 file to be split into 8 chunks using powershell

The file has rows with the first value being the record 'KEY'

I would like to ensure that rows corresponding to the key field value (which is the first value of the row) do not break across files when the split happens.

Here is the simple split I use

```
$i=0
Get-Content -Encoding Default "C:\Test.csv" -ReadCount 10130 | ForEach-Object {
    $i++
    $_ | Out-File -Encoding Default "C:\Test_$i.csv"
}
```

*Sample Data*
0190709,HP16,B,B,3,3,
0190709,HP17,B,B,3,3,
0190709,HP18,B,B,3,3,
0196597,HP11,,CNN,,,
0196597,HP119,,CNN,,,
0196597,HP13,,CNN,,,
01919769,HP11,,ANN,,,
01919769,HP119,,OPN,,,
01919769,HP13,,CNN,,,
01919769,HP14,X,X,X,X,
01919769,HP15,A,A,X,X,
01919769,HP16,S,S,X,X,
01919769,HP17,S,S,5,5,
01919769,HP18,S,S,5,5,
0797819,HP14,X,AX,X,X,
0797819,HP15,X,XA,X,X,
0797819,HP16,X,X,XA,XA,
0797819,HP17,A,A,X,X,
0797819,HP18,A,A,AX,X,

*Expected Output*

Lets say we want 2 chunks of equal size. I would like 2 files like below with the key not split between files. Its ok if the file gets bigger (more lines) in an attempt to prevent page break of the key.

File 1

0190709,HP16,B,B,3,3,
0190709,HP17,B,B,3,3,
0190709,HP18,B,B,3,3,
0196597,HP11,,CaweNN,,,
0196597,HP119,,CNN,,,
0196597,HP13,,CNwN,,,
01919769,HP11,,AawNN,,,
01919769,HP119,,OePN,,,
01919769,HP13,,CNN,,,
01919769,HP14,XY,X,X,X,
01919769,HP15,A,A,XC,XA,
01919769,HP16,S,S,X,X,
01919769,HP17,S,S,5A,5,
01919769,HP18,S,S,5,5,

File 2

0797819,HP14,X,AX,X,X,
0797819,HP15,X,XA,X,X,
0797819,HP16,X,X,XA,XA,
0797819,HP17,A,A,X,X,
0797819,HP18,A,A,AX,X,

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: are the same-key-value rows _contiguous_?

Comment: Do you want the chunks to be _larger_ if breaking up contiguous key values must be avoided, or _smaller_? Larger would be easier to handle.

Comment: The same-key values are contiguous.  The chunks can be larger if it means preventing the page break.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not supplied an example (first couple of lines) of your CSV file, the below function assumes the input csv file is valid.

```
function Split-Csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,          # the full path and filename of the source CSV file

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination,   # the path of the output folder

        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$Chunks = 8,       # the number of parts to split into

        [switch]$FirstLineHasHeaders
    ) 
    # create the destination folder if it does not already exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$Destination'"
        New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    $outputFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
    $content    = Get-Content -Path $Path
    $totalLines = $content.Count

    if ($FirstLineHasHeaders) {
        $headers  = $content[0]
        $partsize = [Math]::Ceiling(($totalLines - 1) / $Chunks)
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Chunks; $i++) {
            $first   = ($i * $partsize + 1)
            $last    = [Math]::Min($first + $partsize -1, $totalLines - 1)
            $newFile = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ('{0}-{1:000}.csv' -f $outputFile, ($i + 1))
            Write-Verbose "Creating file '$newFile'"
            Set-Content -Path $newFile -Value $headers -Force
            Add-Content -Path $newFile -Value $content[$first..$last]
        }
    }
    else {
        $partsize   = [Math]::Ceiling($totalLines / $Chunks)
        for ($i = 1; $i -le $Chunks; $i++) {
            $first   = (($i - 1) * $partsize)
            $last    = [Math]::Min(($i * $partsize) - 1, $totalLines - 1)
            $newFile = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ('{0}-{1:000}.csv' -f $outputFile, $i)
            Write-Verbose "Creating file '$newFile'"
            Set-Content -Path $newFile -Value $content[$first..$last] -Force
        }
    }
}
```

If your input csv file has headers, you need to ensure every 'chunk' file also has these headers.
Use the function **WITH** switch `$FirstLineHasHeaders`

```
Split-Csv -Path 'C:\Test.csv' -Destination 'D:\test' -Chunks 8 -FirstLineHasHeaders -Verbose
```

If your input csv file does NOT have headers, use it like:

```
Split-Csv -Path 'C:\Test.csv' -Destination 'D:\test' -Chunks 8 -Verbose
```